# How to find external ID of ReportsInvoices without Payment

Tags: odoo

I try to customize report of invoice without payment, but i can't fin external ID of report to print. So i opened odoo, then go to setting -> Reporting -> Reporting -> and search for account.invoice 
The problem that i have lot of choices .

Answer (score 0):

*Settings--> Techncial --> Reports --> Invoice*

Is this you want?

[image]

Comment: i have lot of external id...which can choose ?

Comment: That highlighted on is the External ID